# How to use vertical-align on this case

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

First see the screenshot.

[image]
As you see in the previous picture, the words that in the left is more to top, while the right words that in the right is more to bottom, and I'm tried to use `vertical-align` but did not work well.  **[**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg5bS/)**]**
What I want is, the left and right words  to be vertically aligned to textbox.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top_nav">
    <div id="top_nav_container" class="clear">
        <div id="top_nav_left" class="float_left"> 
            <span>
               <a href=""> Message </a>&nbsp;
               <a href=""> Reputation </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="top_nav_right" class="float_right"> 
            <span>
               <a href=""> Login </a>&nbsp; 
               <a href=""> SignUp </a>
            </span>
            <span id="top_nav_search">
               <form action="" method="get">
                   <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
               </form>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type='text'], input[type='password'] {min-width:200px; padding:5px; color:#4F5155;}
form {display:inline;}
.float_left {float:left;}
.float_right {float:right;}
div#top_nav {height:40px; background-color:#eee; padding:5px;}
div#top_nav_container {width:980px; margin:0 auto;}
div#top_nav_left, div#top_nav_right {}
div#top_nav_left span, div#top_nav_right span {}
div#top_nav_left a, div#top_nav_right a{}
div#top_nav_left a:hover, div#top_nav_right a:hover{background-color:#fff;}
span#top_nav_search {margin-left:15px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vertical-align` does not work with floated elements.

You could set line-height though as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg5bS/1/):

```
div#top_nav {height:40px; background-color:#eee; padding:5px;  line-height: 38px}
```

***As a side note:*** don't add the tag names to the rule if you're using id-selectors, e.g:

```
div#top_nav {line-height: 38px} //Bad
#top_nav {line-height: 38px} //Good
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height` as your div height. In your case use `line-height:40px;` in `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox to this:

```
div#top_nav_container {
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    align-items: center;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XYTBW/)